# How to expose css to be configurable on a widget

Tags: jquery, css, widget

I'm trying to build a set of widgets that allow styles to be configurable by each client on their page.

Is there any way to expose classes, ids or something that allow on client side to modify the styles? I tried overriding with `!important` but didn't seem to work

Comment: What do you mean by 'configurable'? How are you allowing (or *attempting* to allow) users to modify the CSS?

Comment: I embedded the widget in a sample page and tried to override the classes with !important on own stylesheets. My goal is to let each client modify styles on their page for the consumed widget

Comment: *"Is there any way to expose classes, ids or something that allow on client side to modify the styles?"*. Yep. In Chrome it's called ***Devtools*** and in Firefox it's ***Web Console***.

Answer (score 0):

Ill start off with this. You should not need to use `!important` to override default styles. You need to check two things to make CSS overrides work elegantly.

1. The override stylesheet is structured properly. If your default stylesheet defines a rule with `.wrapper > .my-container`, the override cant just define a rule for `.my-container` (the default style is a stronger rule and will have priority over the override stylesheet). You must override the same class structure in your override stylesheet.
2. The override styles
   are included after the default stylesheet.

In terms of how to apply custom client-side styles, assuming you want these to be saved and loaded and not be ephemeral, there are a few options.

One is allow clients to customize variables like hex values, widths, etc. You could then store these CSS values in your database and serve a custom stylesheet for that client that overrides those classes. The downside here is the client could potentially store values that look bad or break things, like white on white text (would require validation).

Another option is generate a set of preset classes or "themes" (such as one class for Purple color, another for Yellow color, one for Large size widget, one for small, etc). Then just store which option the client chose and apply it programatically on the front-end. This would not require the same validations, serving custom stylesheets, or require storing CSS strings in your database, but would limit your client's options somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, so there is no way to modify the widget after being consumed, just ways to provide some flexibility to customize them prior to providing them, right?

Comment: Sure you can modify the widget after it is rendered.

You could either A. apply the custom styles via javascript as inline styles (`<div style="...">`), or you can use the custom settings the user chooses to generate a stylesheet and append the stylesheet to the page in a `<style>` tag using javascript (`document.createStyleSheet()`, etc).

I was mentioning more permanent solutions where you would actually store the configuration. If you just want them to be able to customize it in the browser and all their configuration is lost when they leave the page, just do one of the above.